# Products not in the category are showing up in the category

Tags: magento, widget, magento-1.7, categories

This is my first post.

I am using the most up to date magento. I am having trouble understanding why, with the code below, products not in my category "5" are showing up as well. With my category number set it should not include any products not in that category.

```
{{block type="catalog/product_list" category_id="5" template="catalog/product/list.phtml"}}
```

The t-shirt is not in category "5" with the hats. It may be grabbing all my products because so far I only have 3 in the sites beta stages.

This is the only code I can use to show products because the "insert widget" option does not show up on my site.

Thank you for the help!

Kevin

Comment: Category 5 doesn't have "Is Anchor" set to Yes, with the shirt floating around in one of the sub categories, does it? I'm sure you've done the usual cache clean/re-indexing, check to make sure you're not using the flat catalog first.